# P2P->connect() : Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on boolean

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the **Post 2 Post plugin** to create relationship between post types, and I'm trying to connect my Sub-category post type to a category post type in the following function, but I have this error message : Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on boolean.

When I echo the $p2p value, it displays "false", but why ?

Anyone could help me ? Thanks!

Import function :

```
    function import_subCategories(){

    global $co;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tl_events_sous_categories`";
    $result = $co->query($query);

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $my_post = array(

            'post_title' => iconv('ISO-8859-1','UTF-8', $data['headline']),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1,
            'post_type' => 'sub-categorie'
        );

    $the_post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

    // Create the relationship between CATEGORY and SUB CATEGORY
    $p2p = p2p_type('sous_categories_categorie');
    $p2p->connect($the_post_id, $data['pid'], array('date' => current_time('mysql')));

    if(is_wp_error($p2p)){
        echo $p2p->get_error_message();
    }
}
```

}`

Connection types : (in functions.php)

```
    function my_connection_types() {

    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
        'name' => 'sous_categories_categorie',
        'from' => 'sub-categorie',
        'to' => 'categorie'
    ) );
    }
```

EDIT : seems my connection type is registered, because it appears in the WP tools menu : 
[WP Tools menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXPDk.png)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$p2p = p2p_type('sous_categories_categorie');
```

returned false because apparently "sous_categories_categorie" is not a valid connection type.

[The function `p2p_type` is defined as](https://github.com/dbernar1/wp-posts-to-posts/blob/15eb4a868be15d5684e26cd3ba2cd6f4471407bd/api.php#L114)

```
/**
 * Get a connection type.
 *
 * @param string $id Connection type id
 *
 * @return bool|object False if connection type not found, P2P_Connection_Type instance on success.
 */
function p2p_type( $id ) {
    return P2P_Connection_Type::get_instance( $id );
}
```

Now you just need to find out why. Consider putting

```
var_dump(P2P_Connection_Type::get_all_instances())
```

before your call to `p2p_type` to see what types are actually registered.

Make sure there is no typos in the registered types and that you registered the connection type before trying to find it with `p2p_type`. Note that Connection types should not be registered before the 'init' hook.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! The $id parameter to pass to p2p_type() is the 'name' value used in p2p_register_connection_type() ? Because it's what I did but doesn't work

Comment: @Gillian from what I can tell from the source code, yes. See my update.

Comment: Thanks for this indication. It seems P2P_Connection_Type doesn't exist (anymore?) so I used P2P_Connection_Type_Factory instead. I have an empty array... So, my connection type is not registered, but I don't know why.. I don't know what is wrong in my code...

Comment: The connection seems OK, it appears in the WP Tools -> Connection Types menu (just edited my post with the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is due to the hook order, your function was called before p2p initializes connections. The p2p initialize connections on the `wp_loaded` hook

try to move the hook a bit earlier

```
add_action( 'init', 'change_p2p_load', 11 );
function change_p2p_load(){
    remove_action( 'wp_loaded', '_p2p_init' );

    do_action( 'p2p_init' );
}
```